# What reactions occur when pyridine, actic anhydride and citric acid is mixed?

Tags: organic-chemistry

The reaction of pyridine, acetic anhydride, water and citric acid is used as a colorimetric identifier of citric acid. What reactions occur and why does the color change from colorless to greenish? I have been looking everywhere for the answer and have, so far, come up with nothing.

The reaction is made from 1 ml of water containing citric acid, 1.3 ml of pyridine which is then mixed and then 5.7 ml of acetic anhydride is added. Then it is left in a water bath with a temperature of 32 degrees celsius.

Comment: @PhMgBr - I am not so sure. If it were a homework question, I should have been able to learn more about it using popular search engines. I cannot. This sounds like chemistry that happens in a proprietary colorimetic assay kit, and the chemistry in these assay kits is generally obfuscated by the vendor.

Comment: Right @Ben, my bad. Weren't paying enough attention.

Comment: @BenNorris The chemistry here was reported in J. Bio. Chem. in the late 40s. It's not proprietary anymore. The reaction with citric acid, from what I see, gives a red color, not green. Green, supposedly, comes from tartaric acid. [This article] is probably behind a paywall for those not hooked up to the proper IP address, but it's all I've really found so far.

Comment: Okay, then it might be behind a paywall for the OP. Regardless the question can be improved.

Comment: Sorry. [This article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.jbc.org/content/175/2/849.full.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjF0LO5jZvMAhXDdx4KHRTSAesQFggbMAA&usg=AFQjCNGxOtYW2Blje3S3r87_iUHoXzX0Ng&sig2=YrnU2EoQjvOQq14plNJGVA). Should be able to see an abstract (or something, not sure if SD does first page for old articles).

Comment: [This one](http://www.journalofdairyscience.org/article/S0022-0302(58)91152-4/abstract) worked with my VPN connection off.

Comment: We have been doing this experiment as a part of a school project where we produced citric acid by fermentation by Aspergillus niger. We have made several reactions with pure citric acid and some have turned green while others have turned red, most of them have been green. We don't know what factors causes the experiment to turn either green or red. We have used a spectrophotometer and measured at 420 nm as is also done in the aforementioned article if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I don't need a specific answer, i only need some idea of what happens and why, so if anyone has any idea why the color change occurs i would appreciate it very much

Comment: Pyridine as a base and acetic anhydride might facilitate the decarboxylation and elimination of water from citric acid, leading to citraconic (and itaconic) anhydride. These anhydrides **might** form charge transfer complexes with pyridine. If I remember correctly, similar complexes have been observed for pyridine with maleic anhydride.